# Losing strict weak ordering in set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I thought that STL containers set and map provide elements in a strict weak ordering. However, I've found that if I get an iterator through find and change element's value through dereferencing, it doesn't restore order, which violates 23.1.2.2 and 23.3.3.2. Here is the code

```
    int nv = 3;
set<int> s = set<int>();
s.insert(5);
s.insert(10);
s.insert(20);
s.insert(30);
for(set<int>::const_iterator cit = s.begin(); cit != s.end(); ++cit)
    cout<<*cit<<" ";
cout <<endl;
set<int>::iterator it = s.find(10);
*it = nv;
for(set<int>::const_iterator cit = s.begin(); cit != s.end(); ++cit)
    cout<<*cit<<" ";
cout <<endl;
s.insert(40);
for(set<int>::const_iterator cit = s.begin(); cit != s.end(); ++cit)
    cout<<*cit<<" ";
cout <<endl;
```

produces:

```
5 10 20 30
5 3 20 30
5 3 20 30 40
```

Is it a bug in my version of STL (MS VS 2008)? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set's iterator and const_iterator are both constant iterators. You are not allowed to modify set's values, only removing and inserting.

Comment: It can compile only if compiler or library are broken. See, for example, current draft 23.2.4/6: "For associative containers where
the value type is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators."

Comment: @flashnik: Yeah, and this looks like it should be a bug in either the STL or your compiler's implementation. In my opinion this shouldn't be allowed to compile.

Comment: In a C++ 2003 standard there is now such phrase :( I wrote that code just to make absolutely sure that it won't compile, but it did.

Comment: @flashnik -- it's true '97 standard didn't spell that requirement, but following many discussions on newsgroups it was clearly the intent. So it's a good thing they made it explicit requirement now.

Comment: I checked it through Comeau and it didn't compile even with their version of 2002. Though MS and Intel compile it successfully.

Comment: It's ironic how the implementation that actually asserts if your predicate does not define strict weak ordering allows this.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` and `std::set` only perform ordering on insertion.  If you change keys/values of existing items, nothing magic happens, and the result is probably undefined.

To get the desired effect, you must remove the original element, and insert a new one.

Comment: Map doesn't allow to change keys, because it dereferences iterator as `pair<const Key, Value>`. I hoped that during next insertion set would restore order, for example, but that didn't happen. As a result, this set forever has the disorder :(

Comment: @flashnik: You could write a map-like container that does reorder the whole tree every time, but that would be incredibly slow.

Comment: I'd better wanted to get a compilation/runtime error or exception in a code above :(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in that version of STL.

On my g++ I get the following error:
`t2.cpp:18:8: error: assignment of read-only location ‘it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = int, const _Tp& = const int&]()’`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have a gcc to check. It's very good that they treat that as error.

Answer (score 1):

In general case you can't modify the key portion of the associative container element through the iterator. The code simply will not compile.

If your implementation of standard library allows the `*it = nv` assignment, it must be a quirk of that implementation. AFAIK, it is not strictly illegal to allow this assignment to compile. It is more of a quality-of-implementation issue.

The assignment will not compile with Comeau implementation. MS implementation is apparently less restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

Changing an element in a `std::set` can violate the internal ordering and corrupt your data structure. Only some STL implementations protect against this by disallowing modifications to what the `iterator` points to, so you'll have to enforce that constraint yourself.

It's like writing past the logical end of a `std::vector` by calling `reserve` (to make room) and using pointer arithmetic - you can do it, but it'll corrupt your `std::vector`.

If you want to change an element in a set, this should work:

```
std::set<int> my_set;

// initialize my_set ...

std::set<int>::iterator itr = my_set.find(10);
if (itr != my_set.end()) {
    my_set.erase(itr++); // ++ avoids invalidating iterator
    my_set.insert(3);
}
```

You only need to post-increment `itr` if you want to keep using it.

(source: *Effective STL*, "Item 22," Scott Meyers)

Comment: C++ is the best language to shoot yourself in a leg. Thank you for the citation.

Comment: No problem! I highly recommend all three of his books. They explore tons of pitfalls in all different aspects of C++.

Comment: I've read them but didn't remember such case. As I mentioned, I hoped that it's forbidden to write such code but as Gene Bushuyev pointed it'll appear only in C++0x and now some compilers forbid, some not.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` and `std::set` don't **provide** a *strict weak ordering*, they **require** one. You have to provide the ordering (the default is `std::less` which is appropriate for `int`).

If you change the way an element of a `set` or `map` is ordered then you are breaking the requirement as the ordering is not stable.